# Rod Running In Docker Alpine Get Error "chrome-linux/chrome: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, go, chromium, alpine-linux, rod

I'm using [golang/rod](https://go-rod.github.io/#/compatibility) to do something like puppeteer.

Everything is ok in my dev pc, but after I `docker build` and run in alpine it gets the following error:

> chrome-linux/chrome: no such file or directory

**Error Info**

```
Download: https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64/901912/chrome-linux.zip
Progress: 00% 16% 24% 33% 41% 49% 58% 66% 74% 83% 91% 99% 100%
Unzip to: /root/.cache/rod/browser/chromium-901912
Progress: 00% 21% 37% 63% 92% 100%

2021/12/07 11:22:18 [Recovery] 2021/12/07 - 11:22:18 panic recovered:

fork/exec /root/.cache/rod/browser/chromium-901912/chrome-linux/chrome: no such file or directory
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-rod/rod@v0.101.8/lib/utils/utils.go:64 (0xa41a24)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-rod/rod@v0.101.8/must.go:35 (0xb02679)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-rod/rod@v0.101.8/must.go:50 (0xb02828)
/go/src/app/bscase/service.go:733 (0xb38c6c)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.3/context.go:165 (0x999d92)
/go/src/app/common/api/middleware.go:26 (0x999d7a)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.3/context.go:165 (0x98fee1)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.3/recovery.go:99 (0x98fecc)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.3/context.go:165 (0x98f146)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.3/logger.go:241 (0x98f129)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.3/context.go:165 (0x98e67d)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.3/gin.go:489 (0x98e305)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.3/gin.go:445 (0x98de64)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2878 (0x6ddcfa)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1929 (0x6d93a7)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581 (0x4632c0)
```

**Go code** (version 1.17, rod version v0.101.8)

```
l, _ := launcher.New().Set("disable-web-security").
        Set("disable-setuid-sandbox").
        Set("no-sandbox").
        Set("no-first-run", "true").
        Set("disable-gpu").
        Headless(true).
        Launch()
browser := rod.New().ControlURL(l).MustConnect()
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.17 AS builder

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    GOPROXY="https://mirrors.aliyun.com/goproxy/,direct"

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/app

# manage dependencies
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -o /app .

FROM alpine:latest  
# Install base packages
RUN sed -i 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/g' /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache chromium
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /app ./
COPY /configs ./configs
CMD ["./app"]
```

The Rod documentation says ***apk add chromium*** can fix but it didn't work in my container.

Answer (score 4):

> /root/.cache/rod/browser/chromium-901912/chrome-linux/chrome: no such file or directory

This is because [go-rod](https://github.com/go-rod/rod/blob/master/lib/launcher/browser.go#L48) will downloads a prebuilt browser binary from internet if he can't find a valid one.

Unfortunately, the prebuilt one is built with glibc, while `alpine` use `muslc`, this is the root cause you see `no such file or directory`, as that prebuilt one not compatiable with alpine.

YES, from [its doc](https://go-rod.github.io/#/compatibility?id=os), it said:

> On Alpine:
>
> `apk add chromium`

But, you will also need to change your application code to let `go-rod` to find the brower explicitly, otherwise it will still try to use the one on internet, detail see [this](https://go-rod.github.io/#/custom-launch?id=the-launcher-lib).

A simple go file:

**test.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-rod/rod"
    "github.com/go-rod/rod/lib/launcher"
)

func main() {
    path, _ := launcher.LookPath()
    u := launcher.New().Bin(path).MustLaunch()
    rod.New().ControlURL(u).MustConnect().MustPage("https://www.baidu.com/")
    // rod.New().MustConnect().MustPage("https://www.baidu.com/")
}
```

With above, it will try to find the `chromium` you installed with `apk add`, then no error.